# Facebook Like Button - appid breaks it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am creating a facebook like button using the standard code from facebook.  Everything works fine.

When I add my appid though it breaks and the facebook like button dissapears.

I am adding the app id as in the following where 111222333 is the appid:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=111222333";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Are you also calling fb.init somewhere else in your code? providing parameters in the URL of all.js implicitly initialises the SDK

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I am using only the facebook provided code and appending the appId

Comment: Is the app a) in sandbox mode or b) configured with a base domain (in the app settings) which doesn't match the domain the like buttons are on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to append the appid seperately when you can generate the like button codes with the app id from here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

So there arent any permission issues, like the domains arent matching or anything so. It only allows the right app for a given url.